# JavaScript. Filtering objects by multple properties

Tags: javascript

So, I have this simple dataset:

LIVE DEMO: http://jsbin.com/ramuwow/edit?js,console

```
var members = [{
    "id": "1",
    "firstName": "JOHN",
    "lastName": "MARTY"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "firstName": "JONES",
    "lastName": "SMITH"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "firstName": "MARY",
    "lastName": "DOE"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "firstName": "MARGARET",
    "lastName": "KANE"
}];
```

and I have one piece of string from input to search for these objects.

I can do from name and last name to id. But I cannot do first AND last name.

Here is what i have so far:

```
var members = [{"id":"1","firstName":"JOHN","lastName":"MARTY"},{"id":"2","firstName":"JONES","lastName":"SMITH"},{"id":"3","firstName":"MARY","lastName":"DOE"},{"id":"4","firstName":"MARGARET","lastName":"KANE"}];

var filteredNames = members.filter(function(n){
    var query = "MARY DO";

    var splitUp = query.split(" ");
    console.log(splitUp);

    return n.firstName.indexOf(query) > -1 ? n : false || 
        n.lastName.indexOf(query) > -1 ? n : false || 
        n.id.indexOf(query) > -1 ? n : false || 
        n.firstName.indexOf(splitUp[0]) > -1 && n.lastName.indexOf(splitUp[1]);
});

console.log(filteredNames);
```

and that returns:

```
["MARY", "DO"]
["MARY", "DO"]
["MARY", "DO"]
["MARY", "DO"]
[]
```

What am I Doing wrong? The object of `MARY DOE` should appear.

Comment: The last call you make to `.indexOf()` is missing a comparison to `-1`.

Comment: Also, your code *logs* those arrays, but the actual *return value* is that last (empty) array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** You are missing comparison to `-1` at the last.

**Solution :**
Compare the last to `-1` and you will get your object as :

```
var members = [{"id":"1","firstName":"JOHN","lastName":"MARTY"},{"id":"2","firstName":"JONES","lastName":"SMITH"},{"id":"3","firstName":"MARY","lastName":"DOE"},{"id":"4","firstName":"MARGARET","lastName":"KANE"}];

var filteredNames = members.filter(function(n){
    var query = "MARY DO";

    var splitUp = query.split(" ");
    console.log(splitUp);

    return n.firstName.indexOf(query) > -1 ? n : false || 
        n.lastName.indexOf(query) > -1 ? n : false || 
        n.id.indexOf(query) > -1 ? n : false || 
        n.firstName.indexOf(splitUp[0]) > -1 && n.lastName.indexOf(splitUp[1]) > -1;
});

console.log(filteredNames);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
["MARY", "DO"]
["MARY", "DO"]
["MARY", "DO"]
["MARY", "DO"]
[[object Object] {
  firstName: "MARY",
  id: "3",
  lastName: "DOE"
}]
```

**@Credit Goes To @[Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy)**

**JSBin Link :** http://jsbin.com/geziwetudi/edit?js,console

Comment: Argh! How did I not see that! Thank you.